# Bypassing All Subscribers list

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, sales-cloud

We want to use Salesforce data as entry source in Journey Builder for triggered sends to Sales Cloud records (new consents added). For this purpose, first, we would like to avoid these contacts getting registered as new subscribers in All Subscribers master list. Is there a way to bypass this rule (for example, by creating a new publication list)?

Second, in journey settings, when we select "Use email attribute from Contacts", does this mean SFMC will pull a contact's email directly from our Sales Cloud (Account object?) to which the business unit is integrated via the MCC? We would like to send transactional emails to new consent created in Multichannel-Consent object where no email as such exists, but is related to the Account object via `Account_vod__c` (Account_ID).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, there is no way to "bypass" All Subscribers. If you are sending to the subscriber, Salesforce Marketing Cloud needs to store the subscriber details (SubscriberKey and Email Address) in the master All Subscribers list.
2. "Use email attribute from Contacts" does not refer to the contact object in Sales or Service Cloud. This refers to the Contact data in Contact Builder -> Data Designer.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding 2, can you please elaborate? Is that an email related to a contact in all contact list, or to a specific atteibute group?

Comment: You would have to specifically add an attribute group and link a data extension to that attribute group: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_data_designer.htm&type=5